# why does the null space contain nonzero vectors if the linear system is inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am reading through [Boyd's optimization book](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)(section 10.1.1, page 522) and I can't understand the highlighted statement in the screenshot below. I do not understand why there are nonzero vectors in the null space if the KKT system is not solvable?

[image]

Comment: Because the inconsistence of the system doesn't imply the triviality of the solutions of the homogenous system(it's the total opposite)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If KKT system (10.4) is not solvable, then the linear map defined by the KKT (square) matrix in (10.4) is not surjective. ("Surjective" means (10.4) has a solution for every pair of $(q,b)$.)

By the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), it must not be injective.

Therefore the null space of the KKT matrix contains nonzero vectors.

---

May be useful to think about a simpler example.

Suppose $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is a nonzero vector.

If $Ax=b$ has no solution, i.e., "not solvable", then the linear map $x\mapsto Ax$ is not surjective since there is no pre-image for the vector $b$. Then by the rank-nullity theorem, the null space for $A$ must contain nonzero vectors.

Comment: I feel you are mixing the words subjective and surjective?

Comment: @randomndrandom: ah, fixed; thanks!